# Instance Error On Foreign Key Field Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Im stumped and need help on my function.
I have two tables student and student information. Student information is all guardian information of that student. I separated this data from the main student table so you can add as many guardians as you want to a students file with new records.  The error I'm getting is as followed.

Cannot assign "'1'": "StudentInformation.studentpsid" must be a "Student" instance.

Attached you will see my code. Studentpsid in student information is a foreign key from student.

```
def ImportStudentGuardian(request):
    AuthTokenP(request)
    print("Getting student guardian data from SIS for K-8")
    #Pulls K-8 Guardians
    url = "removed for posting"
    payload = {}
    token = APIInformation.objects.get(api_name="PowerSchool")
    key = token.key
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(key)}   
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    encode_xml = response.text.encode('utf8')
    xml_string = ET.fromstring(encode_xml)
    students = xml_string.findall("student")
    for student in students:
      #XML Values
      psid = student.find("id").text
      try:
       mother = student.find("contact").find("mother").text
      except Exception:
       mother = ""   
      try: 
       father = student.find("contact").find("father").text
      except Exception:
       father = "" 
      if Student.objects.filter(studentpsid=psid).exists():  
        print("Accessing guardian information.")
        m = StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=psid,guardian_name = mother, relation = "Mom")   <---- Function Fails here
        print("Record doesn't exist for mom, creating record.")
        m.save()
        d= StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=psid,guardian_name = father, relation = "Dad")
        print("Record doesn't exist for dad, creating record.")
        d.save()
      return ("Updated Guardian Information ")
```

```
Model

class Student(models.Model):
    studentpsid= models.CharField(primary_key = True , default = "", max_length = 50, unique = True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default = "")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1,default = "")
    student_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = "")
    home_room = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = "")
    student_enrollment = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = "")
    school_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15, default = "") 
    email = models.EmailField(default = "")
    projected_graduation_year = models.CharField(max_length = 4, default = "")
    counseling_goal = models.TextField(max_length = 255)
    class_name = models.ManyToManyField(TeacherClass)
    image = models.ImageField(default ="default.png", upload_to ='student_pics')

# Guardian Information For Student 
class StudentInformation(models.Model):
      studentpsid = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = "" ,) 
      guardian_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
      RELATION_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'None'),  
        (1, 'Mom'),
        (2, 'Dad'),
        (3, 'Other'),
             ]
      relation = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices = RELATION_CHOICES,)
      guardian_cell = models.CharField(max_length = 12, default = "")
      guardian_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 80,blank = True, default = "")
      prefered_contact = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = True)
      DAY_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'None'),  
        (1, 'Monday'),
        (2, 'Tuesday'),
        (3, 'Wednesday'),
        (4, 'Thursday'),
        (5, 'Friday'),
             ]
      day_of_week =  models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices = DAY_CHOICES, default = 0 )
      time = models.CharField(max_length= 7, default = "", blank = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a record with the foreign key relation, and instance of the related table should be provided, so the table can maintain a relationship for that particular record.

Get the instance of the `Student` table with the given `psid` and use that while creating the `StudentInformation` record

**EDIT** : Included the part for creating the record only if `mother` and `father` values are available.

```
for student in students:
      #XML Values
    psid = student.find("id").text
    try:
        psid_obj = Student.objects.get(studentpsid=psid) #(pk = psid) also works as the field is primary key
        try:
            mother = student.find("contact").find("mother").text
            m = StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=psid_obj,guardian_name = mother, relation = "Mom")
            m.save()
        except Exception as err1:
            print "Error at Mom", str(err1)   
        try: 
            father = student.find("contact").find("father").text
            d= StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=psid_obj,guardian_name = father, relation = "Dad")
            d.save()
        except Exception as err2:
            print "Error at Dad",str(err2)
    except:
        print "Student Record Not found"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Worked perfectly, however im getting blank records being created during the import if it doesnt see a mom or dad on file. Any advice on my try an except that if it excepts the the mom or father as blank to skip that record and move to next? Thanks

Comment: in try and except block itself you can create the `StudentInformation` object. If 'mom` is found it creates the entry and if doesn't, then raises the exception and moves on to `father`

Comment: Updated the answer for skipping the record creation

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are assigning a **char** data type to the `ForeignKey` field.

You should first get the instance of that `Student`, and then assign it to your `StudentInformation` object, like this:

```py
if Student.objects.filter(studentpsid=psid).exists():  
        print("Accessing guardian information.")
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=psid)  # this will fail if the student doesn't exist
        m = StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=student,guardian_name = mother, relation = "Mom")   <---- Function Fails here
        print("Record doesn't exist for mom, creating record.")
        m.save()
        d= StudentInformation.objects.create(studentpsid=student,guardian_name = father, relation = "Dad")
        print("Record doesn't exist for dad, creating record.")
        d.save()
      return ("Updated Guardian Information ")
```